# Macbook Pro click not working

Tags: macos, macbook, macbook-pro, touchpad

The "click" on my MacBook Pro has started having problems.  I haven't been able to find a root cause on the problem yet.  It doesn't work on either my magic trackpad or the internal trackpad.

I have OSX 10.6.7 on a Spring 2010 17" MBP.

I have booted in safe mode to rebuild the driver cache.  Everything works ok when I restart.  But the click stops working eventually.

I have booted in single user mode and ran applejack.  Again everything works ok when I restart.  But, eventually the click stops working.

Since each "fix" cleans the cache, I am thinking that it's some sort of caching problem, but what???

Answer (score 0):

What third-party human input device (HID) drivers do you have installed?  I've seen problems like this when I was messing around with USB Overdrive. Try disabling — or better yet, uninstalling — any third-party drivers or other software that messes with HID settings, and see if the problem goes away.

Also, if you do a simple reboot, does the problem go away?  Or are you sure you have to rebuild your kextcache to make it go away?

Comment: First...love the Calvin reference in the name. Very nice! I don't have and additional HID drivers installed last time I checked.  I will go through with a finer tooth comb and see if I find anything.

A simple reboot doesn't solve the problem.  If the problem occurs I HAVE to either run safe mode/restart or run applejack in single-user mode.